# plt.savefig() in Python crashes with .jpg format even after installing pillow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save a figure with `plt.savefig()` is python **as a jpg or jpeg format** but I keep having this error:

```py
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 468, in set_cursor
    self.canvas.get_property("window").set_cursor(cursord[cursor])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_cursor'
```

Pillow is installed and these are the supposed formats of images supported by matplotlib 3.2.1 on my computer:
(supported formats: eps, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff)

The code works properly with other formats like pdf or png.
This is my code (very simple):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 3, 5, 9, 11])
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('Books Read')
plt.savefig('book.jpg')
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. So I would assume it must have something todo with your setup.

Comment: Can you `plt.show()` or does this also produce errors?

Comment: No plt.show() works fine :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't intend to use `plt.show()` then simply add the following:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

**book.jpg:**

[image: plot]

## EDIT:

Looking at the documentation linked to in my comment below

> you should avoid explicitly calling use() unless absolutely necessary.

Instead you can create a `matplotlibrc` file in the same directory as your script and change the backend that way by adding `backend : Agg` or `backend : TkAgg` to that file.

Comment: **Side note:** if you *do* intend to show the fig at any point, use `TkAgg` instead of plain `Agg`.

Comment: Oh I see thank you very much. But do you have any idea why I can't save figures as jpg without adding `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` or  `matplotlib.use('Agg')` ?

Comment: I guess you're using by default a backend that doesn't support writing jpeg files. You might be using an interactive backend. See here for more details: https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend